# URL performing an action on a php page

Tags: php

I have a web form that when used creates a URL that can be used to take you back to the web form - populating the form as you did originally.

So for example, if you filled in the 'update' and 'update time' fields, the URL created would have this added:

```
$url .= "&update=".$update;
$url .= "&upd_time=".$upd_time;
```

I have added checkboxes to the form, and want the boxes a user selected show as selected originally to show as checked again, when using the URL to return to the form.

Is that possible - hopefully I have explained that clearly..

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible, and no, you have not properly explained, what part of this is a _problem_ you can’t solve on your own.

Comment: I am not sure what to add to the URL to ensure a checkbox is checked.

Comment: It'd be very helpful if you could expand your question with a code sample of your best effort to solve the problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can set in URL &checkbox=1 and then use this code to retrieve if the checkbox were checked or not:

```
$checked = $_GET['checkbox'] == "1" ? "checked" : "";
```

Then you can write in your html form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" <?=$checked?> >
```

If the URL checkbox is 1 then the PHP code write in the html input the checked attribute for display the input as checked.